# What block version is this: d9b4bef9 (decimal: 3652501241)?

Tags: blockchain, block, bip9-version-bits

I'm trying to parse the blockchain directly from the .dat files. The parser works well up until I run into these blocks, with the version appearing as "d9b4bef9" (already reversed).

What is this version, and what special rules does it have?

Comment: I don't think that *is* a version. I think that's the protocol magic bytes: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_structure

Comment: https://www.yours.org/content/the-true-satoshi-nakamoto-0f396f07b417